# NIntegrate (Helium Singlet and Triplet)

Tags: numerical-integration, simplifying-expressions, variational-calculus

I have two integrals that I am calculating using nested NIntegrate. One is for the singlet helium atom and another for triplet. (here, I am calculating variationally the approximate energies and eigenstates of 1s2p state of neutral helium).

*First Integral (Singlet):*

```
f1Final[R2_?NumericQ,θ2_?NumericQ,α_?NumericQ,β_?NumericQ]:=2*Pi*NIntegrate[
((α^3 β^5 (E^(-R2 α-R1 β) R1 Cos[θ1]+E^(-R1 α-R2 β) R2 Cos[θ2])^2) R1^2 Sin[θ1])/(2 π^2 Sqrt[R1^2+R2^2-2 R1 R2 Cos[θ2]]),
{R1,0,∞},{θ1,0,π},
Method->{"GlobalAdaptive","MaxErrorIncreases"->10000,Method->"GaussKronrodRule"},AccuracyGoal->5,PrecisionGoal->5]

fFinal[{α_?NumericQ,β_?NumericQ}]:=2*Pi*NIntegrate[
f1Final[R2,θ2,α,β] R2^2 Sin[θ2],{R2,0,∞},{θ2,0,π},
 Method->{"GlobalAdaptive","MaxErrorIncreases"->10000,Method->"GaussKronrodRule"},AccuracyGoal->5,PrecisionGoal->5]
```

*Second Integral (Triplet):*

```
f1FinalMin[R2_?NumericQ,θ2_?NumericQ,α_?NumericQ,β_?NumericQ]:=2*Pi*NIntegrate[
((α^3 β^5 (-E^(-R2 α-R1 β) R1 Cos[θ1]+E^(-R1 α-R2 β) R2 Cos[θ2])^2) R1^2 Sin[θ1])/(2 π^2 Sqrt[R1^2+R2^2-2 R1 R2 Cos[θ2]]),
{R1,0,∞},{θ1,0,π},
Method->{"GlobalAdaptive","MaxErrorIncreases"->10000,Method->"GaussKronrodRule"},AccuracyGoal->5,PrecisionGoal->5]

fFinalMin[{α_?NumericQ,β_?NumericQ}]:=2*Pi*NIntegrate[
f1FinalMin[R2,θ2,α,β]*R2^2*Sin[θ2],
{R2,0,∞},{θ2,0,π},
Method->{"GlobalAdaptive","MaxErrorIncreases"->10000,Method->"GaussKronrodRule"},AccuracyGoal->5,PrecisionGoal->5]
```

The first integral is for the singlet state. The second for triplet state. The wave function goes to zero, for the singlet state, when $R1=R2$ and $\theta1$ = $\theta2$. For some reason, the two integrals give the same values for any input of $\alpha$ and $\beta$. Does anyone know why this might be the case? The two integrals should differ, because the triplet state (and therefore the integrand above for f1FinalMin) goes to zero for $R1=R2$ and $\theta1$ = $\theta2$. NIntegrate doesn't seem to be working properly.

Also, if anyone has an idea for a better way to perform these integrals, that would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: Please post copyable code, not images. Nobody likes to type all this code trying to answer your question.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries sorry, i am using this for the first time. I just copied and pasted the code above. Doesn't look pretty. But if you want to run it, you could probably just copy it and run it in mathematica.

Comment: There are formatting tools for your post. Help can be found by using the ? link at the top right corner of the edit box

Comment: The last edited removed all code. Without that, answering seems very difficult.

Comment: @YvesKlett Ooops. Sorry, I was trying to make the code more readable.

Comment: Okay! Please use the code format (indent four spaces) and paste directly from *Mathematica*, so we can paste back from here.

Comment: The reason why the integrals are equal is because the integrands only differ in the sign under the square, hence in the sign of the cross term. But the cross term integrates to zero. So there seems to be no *Mathematica* issue here. It boils down to `Integrate[Sin[\[Theta]1]Cos[\[Theta]1],{\[Theta]1,0,\[Pi]}]`.

Comment: @YvesKlett the indent did the trick thanks!

Comment: @Jens I don't  think that's the case. Once you expand the square terms, the middle term will have a minus sign in the second integral. Also, I have (in a book, not sure how I could integrate this analytically in Mathematica) an analytically calculated solution, which clearly shows that there should be a difference between the two integration evaluations.

Comment: I formatted your code (fancy typesetting messes the plain text up somewhat bad), please check if everything is still correct. Also, do you have an actual call to your functions to compute something?

Comment: @YvesKlett yea. i evaluate using `fFinalMin[{2, 0.49}]` and `fFinal[{2, 0.49}]`

Comment: @Jens I just did the integration by expanding the squares. The cross term contribution is very tiny ~10^(-19). There seems to be the problem. But the book solution that I have (which did this analytically) has diff values for the overall integrals.

Answer (score 4):

For problems like these, I like to take small steps and check each one, so please bear with me.  First, we write the two exponential functions, which I am calling f1 and f2.  Then write the next two more complicated functions, called gSing for singlet and gTrip for triplet.  Then write an expression for the denominator and an expression for the volume elements.

```
f1 = Exp[-α*r1 - β*r2]; 
f2 = Exp[-α*r2 - β*r1]; 

gSing = f2*r1*Cos[θ1] + f1*r2*Cos[θ2]; 
gTrip = -f2*r1*Cos[θ1] + f1*r2*Cos[θ2]; 

d = Sqrt[r1^2 + r2^2 - 2*r1*r2*Cos[θ2]]; 

vol = r1^2*Sin[θ1]*r2^2*Sin[θ2];
```

The above expressions do not have some of your constant factors in them, but that is okay for now.  Next we write expressions for the singlet and triplet integrands, and for the difference.

```
hSing = (gSing^2/d)*vol; 
hTrip = (gTrip^2/d)*vol; 
hDiff = FullSimplify[hSing - hTrip]
```

The result looks like this $$
\frac{r_1^3 r_2^3 \sin(2\theta_1) \sin(2\theta_2) e^{(\alpha +\beta)(-(r_1+r_2))}}{\sqrt{r_1^2+r_2^2-2r_1 r_2 \cos (\theta_2)}}$$
The difference in the two integrands contains a factor of $\sin(2\theta_1)$ which integrates to zero.  Therefore, the difference in the two integrals must be zero, even though the integrands are different.

If we go back and look at where that $sin2\theta_1$ term is coming from, it looks right.  So, I'm going to suggest maybe the formula is wrong.  Since you mentioned the 1S2P state, I would expect one electron to have the ground state (1S) wavefunction and the other to have the excited state (2P) wavefunction.  So, that might be something to check / verify.  Whatever the problem is, as long as that $sin2\theta_1$ term is there, Mathematica is right to give the same answer for the two integrals.

Another thing that might help is to look at Problem 5.11 in Griffiths.  He gives a hint about a similar integral for the $(1S)^2$ state.  He says we should integrate w.r.t. $d^3r_2$ first.  He also says to integrate $r_2$ from zero to $r_1$ and then from $r_1$ to infinity.  *Introduction to Quantum Mechanics* by David J. Griffiths, second edition.

Since we have taken electron 1 to be on the polar axis with $\theta_1=0$, maybe we should not be integrating w.r.t. $\theta_1$ at all.  If we set $\theta_1=0$ to begin with, and remove the $\sin(\theta_1)$ term from the volume element expression, then we get a new expression for the difference in integrands.  Using the hint in Griffiths, here is how this new expression could be integrated symbolically.

```
vol2 = r1^2*r2^2*Sin[θ2]; 
hSing2 = (gSing^2/d)*vol2 /. θ1 -> 0; 
hTrip2 = (gTrip^2/d)*vol2 /. θ1 -> 0; 
hDiff2 = FullSimplify[hSing2 - hTrip2]
```

Now to integrate hDiff2, we want to integrate w.r.t. $\theta_2$ first, per Griffiths.  We divide the integral into an outer integral with $r_2>r_1$ and and inner integral with $r_2<r_1$.  We code it like this:

```
outer1 = Integrate[hDiff2, {θ2, 0, Pi},
  Assumptions -> {α > 0, β] > 0, r1 > 0, r2 > r1}]
inner1 = Integrate[hDiff2, {θ2, 0, Pi},
  Assumptions -> {α > 0, β] > 0, r2 > 0, r2 < r1}]
```

Next, integrate w.r.t. $r_2$ from zero to $r_1$ and from $r_1$ to infinity.  And finally, combined the results and integrate w.r.t. $r_1$ from zero to infinity.

```
outer2 = Integrate[outer1, {r2, r1, Infinity},
  Assumptions -> {α > 0, β > 0, r1 > 0}]
inner2 = Integrate[inner1, {r2, 0, r1},
  Assumptions -> {α > 0, β > 0, r1 > 0}]
```

diffInt = Integrate[inner2 + outer2, {r1, 0, Infinity},
  Assumptions -> {α > 0, β > 0}]

So, that is the basic concept.  The justification is that if $\theta_1$ was allowed to vary, then the distance between electrons would depend on $\theta_1$, but it does not.  Don't forget all the constant factors I have left out, including a factor of 2 on that second volume element.

Comment: (+1) for taking the effort - this confirms that it's not a *Mathematica* issue.

Comment: did this work for you @Louis? I agree with you about $\theta_1$ (although Griffiths doesn't do what you did, which is confusing me more) but if I do the integral as you suggest i do not get the right result for singlet and triplet states; i took care of the constants too. 
the singlet state fshould give (assuming that the integral result is singInt) `singInt+ 1/2 ($\alpha$^2 + $\beta$^2) - 2 $\alpha$ - $\beta$ = -2.12161`. what is bothering me is that i get the right result for the singlet state but the triplet state is the same which makes sense given your analysis but shouldn't be the case.

Comment: @PawanDhakal.  Yes, it worked for me.  That is, for the Coulomb interaction energy of the electrons in the 1S2P state, I get 0.548 for the singlet and 0.445 for the triplet in units of $q^2 Z/a_0$.  I get positive values for repulsion, which seems to agree with the energy level diagram for He.  Are we calculating the same thing?  What is the right answer?  Also, what textbook(s) are you looking at?  I can show my full calculation, if you want.  I will check it a few more times.

Comment: @Louis Yes. the repulsion should give positive values. The total energies for singlet state should be -57.76 eV (about -2.12 atomic units) and triplet should be lower by 0.22 eV. If you have the chance to look at P.J.E Peebles (Quantum Mechanics, Chapter 6), he does the calculation for 1s2p state and derives the results. 
But, when I do what you suggest, the energy values (after minimization) are -67.74eV for singlet and -67.79eV for triplet.
The book I was mentioning was the Griffiths one, which doesn't do $\theta_1 = 0$ during the calculation of the ground state energy.